Can the separability of a space depend on the axiom of choice?
Does there exist a topological space $X$ such that in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, $X$ is separable, but such that it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $X$ is not separable? The motivation behind this question is that the proof that a subset of a separable metric space is again separable requires some form of choice, as far as I know.

There can be a set of reals which as a subspace it is not separable. But this set of reals is not, in a good way, definable that we can talk about $X$ as an abstract topological space like we can talk about "the reals".

@AsafKaragila Can you elaborate on that construction?

What do you mean by "construction"?

@AsafKaragila I'm trying to ask where I can read more about the existence of such sets of reals

The usual example is Cohen's first model, one place to read about this is Jech's "Axiom of Choice" book in Chapter 5. You can also look at Herrlich's "Axiom of Choice" book, where the construction of the model is not given, but it does work out some of the interesting consequences of "There is an infinite Dedekind-finite set of real numbers".

@AsafKaragila Thanks. Do I understand correctly that such a set is Dedekind-finite, hence contains no countable subset, and hence cannot be separable?

Yes that's correct.
